# CvSVM predict not returning correct value

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I was trying the example detailed within this [article](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html).

Training and further the loop to identify hyper-plane works well.

```
i.e.
// Data for visual representation
    int width = 512, height = 512;
    Mat image = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);

    // Set up training data
    float labels[4] = {1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0};
    Mat labelsMat(4, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);

    float trainingData[4][2] = { {501, 10}, {255, 10}, {501, 255}, {10, 501} };
    Mat trainingDataMat(4, 2, CV_32FC1, trainingData);

    // Set up SVM's parameters
    CvSVMParams svmparam;
    svmparam.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
    svmparam.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
    svmparam.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);

    // Train the SVM
    CvSVM svm;
    svm.train(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), svmparam);
    svm.save("Training.xml");

    // Train the SVM
    svm->train(trainingDataMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);

    Vec3b blue(255, 0 ,0);
    Vec3b green(0, 255, 0);
    for(int x = 0; x < image.rows; ++x)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < image.cols; ++y)
        {
            Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1,2) << y,x);
            float response = svm.predict(sampleMat);

            if(response == 1)
                image.at<Vec3b>(x,y) = green;
            else if(response == -1)
                image.at<Vec3b>(x,y) = blue;
        }
    }
```

But when I am trying to get support vector using api (svm.get_support_vector(i);), it returns a very small number (as 0.000876529e-28). Hence after type-casting to "int" the coordinates X,Y are becoming 0,0 respectively. So, even after getting the hyperplane, I am unable to get respective support - vectors.

```
i.e.
for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
    {
        const float* v = svm.get_support_vector(i);
        cv::Point resCenter((int) v[0], (int) v[1]);
        std::cout << v[0] << ":" << v[1] << "= " << resCenter << std::endl;
        circle( image,  resCenter, 6,  Scalar(128, 128, 128), thickness, lineType);
    }
```

I tried Normalizing the coordinate position as

```
X' = x - MinR / (MaxR - MinR)   // Here MinR and MaxR are size of cols (0, 512)
Y' = y - MinR / (MaxR - MinR)   // Here MinR and MaxR are size of rows (0, 512)
```

As I am new to Machine learning, I would be thankful, if you would suggest me something to read on the following questions:

1. What does Train internally do with the feature-vector we are passing. (I understand it creates a category with respect to Labels provided, but how is it happening.)
2. Internal functioning of predict.

Any pointers to understanding these would help me. Thanks for your precious time in advance.

Comment: What do you expect the support vector to be? What does your _predicted image_ look like?

Comment: Ans.1 The support vector should return the respective coordinates on which a gray circle should be drawn, as it is shown in example following the article.

Ans.2: Resultant image should be pointing the border points ({501, 10}, {255, 10}, {501, 255}) of Hyper-plane among both classes (in gray color).

Comment: Do you see the difference between your code and the example you reference?

Comment: Yeah, after calculation of Hyperplane predict is working ok to classify the pixels of resultant image (as green and blue) but when I am trying to get the support-vector "svm.get_support_vector(i);" then it's returning some small fractional number which is becoming 0 after integral type-cast. Leading the resultant gray circle to the (0,0) of pixel. {{{Whereas, the article is showing the gray-circles as boundary points of Hyper-plane}}}.
The code is exactly same as "diff" is returning nothing.